# Fresnel diffraction approximation (parabolic waves)

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction, approximations

The Huygens-Fresnel principle (*Introduction to Fourier Optics*, Goodman),

$$ U(x,y)=\frac{z}{i\lambda}\int_\Sigma U(\xi,\eta)\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}d\xi d\eta\,, $$

where $\cos \theta=\frac{z}{r}$, shows that the field produced by a punctual source propagates as spherical waves because of the phase $ \vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}$. Is it safe to say that in the Fresnel approximation,

$$ U(x,y)=\frac{e^{ikz}}{i\lambda z}\int U(\xi,\eta) e^{\frac{ik}{2z}[(x-\xi)^2+(y-\eta)^2]}d\xi d\eta \, ,$$

the field propagates as parabolic waves, since the phase takes the form of a paraboloid?

Comment: I edited this post in a few ways. Please note: 1) This is a website for physics questions and answers. Therefore, you don't have to say "My question is...". We know that every post is a question. 2) Asking for general commentary may actually get your question *closed*. We discourage vague questions and even open ended questions are usually considered inappropriate. Focused, specific questions are the best and most likely to get answers. 3) Please do pay attention to spelling. The editor underlines errors in red so really there's no reason you can't take a few seconds to fix them. Thanks!

Comment: does anyone know if we can say that?

Answer (score 2):

I had this doubt once. Shape of a wavefront is a surface of constant phase in space. So, when you combine $e^{ikz}$ & $e^{\frac{ik}{2z}[(x-ξ)^2 + (y-η)^2]}$, the total phase comes out to be $kz + {\frac{k}{2z}[(x-ξ)^2 + (y-η)^2]} $ and when you find the surfaces of constant phase they turn out to be ellipses. The parabolic wavefronts will be realized when you make an assumption that when z varies then variation in  ${\frac{k}{2z}[(x-ξ)^2 + (y-η)^2]} $ is much less then variation in $kz$ due to variation in z. This can be justified by taking partial derivative of both ${\frac{k}{2z}[(x-ξ)^2 + (y-η)^2]} $  & $kz$ with respect to z, you will find that variation due to z in the denominator is less, because its derivative involves $\frac{1}{z^2}$, than the variation due to z in numerator as it doesn't involve any $\frac{1}{z^2}$ kind of decreasing term. So, you can treat $z$ in the denominator of ${\frac{k}{2z}[(x-ξ)^2 + (y-η)^2]} $ as a constant, say c, and in $kz$ as variable. The surface of constant phase will have the equation as $$kz + {\frac{k}{2c}[(x-ξ)^2 + (y-η)^2]} = \gamma$$ ,where $\gamma$ is the constant phase for a surface. This gives you a paraboloid with its axis as $x=ξ$ & $y=η$ and vertex as $(ξ,η,\frac{\gamma}{k})$. As the phase changes, vertex of the paraboloid changes.